# What is CUI.exe?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I went to grab some coffee, and when I came back this app was on my taskbar. No UI comes up when I click it, but I have no idea what it is. It's called CUI.exe, and googling that just gives me a bunch of those "dll info" sites that basically tell me it's an executable, then helpfully tell me what an executable is. Yay. It does sound like it's part of Windows though...

So, does anyone know what this is? Why it would just pop up on the taskbar? Is it safe to kill?

[image]

Comment: Based on my research it belongs to Symantec product.  It is not part of Windows.  Verify the location of the process is in`C:\Program Files\Symantec\Endpoint Agent\cui.exe`

Comment: @Ramhound There is a Symantec folder under Program files (x86) but no CUI.exe in there or it's one subfolder. The Symantec folder under regular Program Files is empty...

Comment: So have you identified the location of the file in question on your system?  It might be a common third-party file, what it is not, is a Microsoft file.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok, found it under Manufacturer/Endpoint Agent... so looks like it is part of Symantec. Feel free to post it as  an answer and I'll mark it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same thing appear on my Windows 7 taskbar.
I am using Symantec Endpoint Protection v14 build 3897 (14.0.3897.1101) and closing the cui.exe did not close or disable SEP.  I have no information about which SEP function uses cui.exe or why it would get stuck on the taskbar, but there appears to be no harm in closing it.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this record here](http://systemexplorer.net/file-database/file/cui-exe).  It appears to be safe:

> This executable is part of the Endpoint Agent for Endpoint Protection suite from Symantec Corporation - antivirus and protection application for PCs and VMwares, check more info on http://www.symantec.com/endpoint-protection/?inid=us_ps_flyout_prdts_endptprot